# Shorthand for multiple equivalency checks in c

Tags: c

Is there any shorthand for the following in C?

```
if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'd' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'k') {
    ...
}
```

In python there's something like the `in` operator where it can be done like:

```
if (letter in ['a','d','i','k']) {
   ...
}
```

How are multiple equivalency checks normally done in C? Or is long-form the only way?

Comment: How about `strchr("adik", letter)` ?

Comment: There is no syntax for that in C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sure that works: want to post an example explaining how that works?

Comment: Guess `switch(letter)` doesn't count as "shorthand".

Comment: you can create your own function to shorthand it

Comment: @dxiv I would upvote your answer about `switch`.

Comment: I think there might be some variadic macro trick too... But will leave it as idea to some other potential answerer :)

Comment: @mch [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65729536/5538420), with some macro wrappers to make it a bit more concise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than scanning a string with (e.g. `strchr` et. al.), if you're doing this a *lot* and you have more chars in your "set", you could use a translation table.

---

The initialization may seem a bit cumbersome, but it would be very fast to execute.

```
char list[256] = {
    ['a'] = 1,
    ['d'] = 1,
    ['i'] = 1,
    ['k'] = 1,
};

int
match(int letter)
{

    return list[(unsigned char) letter];
}
```

---

A more general way may be to initialize the table *once* from a string.

```
char list[256];

void
init(char *list,const char *str)
{

    memset(list,0,256);
    for (;  *str != 0;  ++str)
        list[(unsigned char) *str] = 1;
}

int
match(int letter)
{

    return list[(unsigned char) letter];
}

int
main(void)
{

    init(list,"adik");

    // ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> thanks, could you explain this initialization a bit more? `char list[256] = {     ['a'] = 1, ['d'] = 1,...}` ? I've never seen that notation before.

It's what's called a "*designated* initializer".

There are *two* types: one for arrays, and one for structs. They have different syntax.

Normal initializers are "positional".

With any initializer, any position that is *not* explicitly initialized gets a value of 0.

One of the key features is that designated initializers can appear in *any* order, unlike positional ones.

Since you have `python` experience, they are [particularly for the struct variants], similar/analogous to keyword arguments in python function calls.

---

**Arrays:**

For example, `['a'] = 1` statically initializes the array element just as if you had done (in executable code): `list['a'] = 1;`

These are equivalent:

```
int arr[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int arr[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 7 };
int arr[10] = { [4] = 7 };
```

And, these:

```
int arr[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int arr[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6 };
int arr[10] = { [5] = 6, [4] = 7 };
```

---

**Structs:**

The initializer syntax is:

```
.sym = value
```

Here's an example:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
    const char *z;
};

struct foo str1 = { 0, 23, "hello" };
struct foo str2 = { .z = "hello", .y = 23 };
```

---

**Combinations:**

We can combine/intersperse these for more complex scenarios:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
    const char *z;
};

struct bar {
    int j;
    const char *k;
};

struct joint {
    struct foo j_foo[3];
    struct bar j_bar[4];
    const char *jname;
};

struct joint jlist[6] = {
    [3] = {
        .jname = "jlist[3]",
        .j_bar = {
            [2] = { .j = 19, .k = "jbar2" },
            [0] = { .j = 62 },
        },
        .j_foo = {
            [1] = { .y = 37, .z = "jfoo1" },
            [0] = { .y = 17 },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: thanks, could you explain this initialization a bit more? `char list[256] = {
    ['a'] = 1, ['d'] = 1,...}` ? I've never seen that notation before.

Comment: Good answer with a pedagogical value! You might add that this notation is standard C as from C99, so it might not be available on some outdated embedded systems development environments.

Answer (score 4):

If `letter` is a byte value, you could write:

```
if (memchr("adik", letter, 4))
```

or if `letter` is known to not be a null byte<sup>1</sup>:

```
if (strchr("adik", letter))
```

`strchr()` and `memchr()` are declared in `<string.h>`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `strchr("adik", 0)` will return a pointer to the null terminator of the string `"adik"`, so the test would evaluate to true for `letter == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general shorthand for this, but for checking if a character is one of several you can use a standard function for searching a character in a string:

```
#include <string.h>

//.....
    if (strchr("adik", letter) { // This will return NULL if not found
      //  .....
    }
//.....
```

Comment: this assumes that `letter` is a byte value and not `0`.

Comment: … because `strchr` considers the terminating null byte in the first argument to be part of the string, so, if `letter` is 0, it will return a pointer to that terminating byte.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical C way to check an integer type against a (small) set of constant values is with a `switch` statement.

```
switch(c)
{
case 'a':
case 'd':
case 'i':
case 'k':
    /* do something */
    break;
default:
    /* do something else */
    break;
}
```

This can be made somewhat more "*shorthand*" at the price of some macro trickery.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NARGS(...) NARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define NARGS_(_4, _3, _2, _1, N, ...) N

#define CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT_(A, B)
#define CONCAT_(A, B) A##B

#define CASES_1(C, ...) case C
#define CASES_2(C, ...) case C: CASES_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CASES_3(C, ...) case C: CASES_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CASES_4(C, ...) case C: CASES_3(__VA_ARGS__)

#define CASES(...) CONCAT(CASES_, NARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) (__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    char s[] = { 'a', 'K', 'x' };
    for(int n = 0; n < sizeof(s); n++)
    {
        switch(s[n])
        {
        CASES('a', 'd', 'i', 'k'):
            printf("char '%c' lowercase\n", s[n]); break;
        CASES('A', 'D', 'I', 'K'):
            printf("char '%c' uppercase\n", s[n]); break;
        default:
            printf("char '%c' not found\n", s[n]); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output from code above using [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/39Mdbj) (for some reason [msvc](https://rextester.com/MVF72203) requires an extra level of expansion):

```
char 'a' lowercase
char 'K' uppercase
char 'x' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

> How are multiple equivalency checks normally done in C? Or is long-form the only way?

If you want something similar to Python, you can put the values in an array and loop through them. You can wrap that into a function or macro, if needed.

Comment: thanks. Could you show a basic example of that: I assume something like `letters char[] = {'a','d','i','k'};...` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, although you got the syntax reversed: `char letters[]`. But please note that I was answer for the general case; if you only need the `char` case, you got `strchr()`.